# EF virtual collection with custom get method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible in EF to have a virtual collection that has a custom query to the data it pulls?

For instance, if I have a class `person.cs` and I have a property in that class: `public ICollection<job> jobs`, but I want that property to be defined by a custom query that I write, for instance, `_context.jobs.where(j => j.backup_person_id == id).select(j);` rather than defaulting to look for just `person_id` on the `jobs` table.

Is that possible? If so, how is it achieved?

**[Edit]**

More specifically: let's say the `jobs` table has the two columns `manager` and `main_lead`. I then want my `person.cs` class to have the properties: `ICollection<job> managerJobs` which contains all of the `<job>` entries where the `manager` field matches the `person_code` field of that `person` and `ICollection<job> main_leadJobs` which contains all of the `<job>` entries where the `main_lead` field matches the `person_code` field of that `person`,

In my head, it seems pretty simple: `ICollection<job> managerJobs` = `select * from tbl_jobs where manager = person_code` and `ICollection<job> main_leadJobs` = `select * from tbl_jobs where main_lead = person_code`

I hope that makes more sense than what I had above

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. Could you share more information on what are you trying to achieve? Because it doesn't seem logical right now.

Comment: As far as I get you want to redefine `collection` of `jobs` for one `person` to be a `collection` of `jobs` of another hardcoded `person`. This is not how it should work.

Comment: I tried to clarify above

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. However, what you want to achieve, more generally, is possible, just in a different way. See the MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicitFilter

In a situation where you a dealing with a specific `person`, rather than including `jobs` generally, you can do:

```
var person = _context.People.Find(personId);
_context.Entry(person)
    .Collection(b => b.jobs) 
    .Query() 
    .Where(j => j.backup_person_id == backupId) 
    .Load();
```

Then, when you accessed the `person.jobs` collection, it would only be those filtered items. This means you've got two queries, though, whereas if you just eargerly loaded all jobs via `Include`, it would be done in a single query.

If you have multiple people you're working with though, this explicit load would have to be done multiple times, meaning a query for each person (N+1). In that situation, you're better off querying each entity individually:

```
var people = db.People.Where(...).ToList();
var jobs = db.Jobs.Where(m => people.Select(m => m.Id).Contains(m.person_id) && m.backup_person_id == backupId).ToList();
```

In other words, you're querying just jobs belonging to the specific selected people and then further limiting that by your criteria, which in this case is the id of the backup person. Then, as you're iterating through the people, you can filter `jobs` in memory to just the jobs that belong to the current person in context.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have 2 follow-up questions. So there is no way to put that type of query into the class definition? I would have to manually write it out every time I wanted to use it? Also, what exactly makes the syntax you wrote `in memory`?